# read_csv pandas, encoding issue

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv-file with a list of keywords that I want to use for some filtering of texts.

I saved the csv-file, and tried to open it in my notebook using pd.from_csv('file.csv', encoding = 'UTF-8')

This didn't work even though I specified the encoding to this encoding type.

After some searching, I found some different encodings, I decided to go for

```
keywords = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding = 'latin1')
```

gets me the actual keywords, but when inspecting the words, I get that the spaces are passed as follows:

```
['falsification\xa0',
 'détournement\xa0de\xa0subsides\xa0',
 'parachutes\xa0dorés\xa0',...]
```

about the csv-file: it has two columns of keywords, one column in dutch, the other one in French. The issue with the spaces persists even when I use other encodings like

Comment: I believe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513720/pythongot-xa0-instead-of-space-in-csv-and-cannot-remove-or-convert/37513826

Comment: Thanks, I was performing a similar solution (writing a script to get rid of them). However, what I don't understand is why these \xa0's show up? They don't show up for every space, so what is the difference? I am manually writing the keyword csv file and am simply using the spacebar, why is it being encoded/decoded differently?
Also, my problem is different since in the question you mentioned, the csv file seems to contain these \xa0 in the file itself whilst for me this is not the case.

Comment: You've probably entered the data with a different encoding than the one you later read the file with.
In a file, all the data is actually a sequence of 0 and 1 (most of the time represented in hex that is marked with \x and the 2 hexadecimal digits), the encoding only tells how to show this data.
It is possible that the encoding you chose sometimes had the digits it represents as space but sometimes didn't so left it as hex.
If you want to fully understand it I recommend you try to convert between binary representation to hex/decimal/ ASCI.
As for your problem, I'll try UNICODE encoding.

Comment: Just noticed what you've written about the different languages. This may be the reason for the difference. Still will try Unicode, but if it won't work it is possible you'll need to decode the different columns differently.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful remarks, I will try splitting the keywords in different csv files per language and let you know tomorrow!